# Store doesn't recognise my delete action from the dispatcher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I am trying to implement a delete method for my todo list app. I ran into a problem where it tells me that "this.deleteTodo is not a function" in TodoStore.js. I haven't really tried much as I don't know where the problem comes from. What could be the issue here?

My TodoStore.js

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";

class TodoStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.todos = [
      {
        id: 113464613,
        text: "Go Shopping"
      },
      {
        id: 235684679,
        text: "Pay Water Bill"
      },
    ];
  }

  createTodo(text) {
    const id = Date.now();

    this.todos.push({
      id,
      text,
    });

    this.emit("change");
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.todos;
  }

  handleActions(action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case "CREATE_TODO": {
        this.createTodo(action.text);
        break;
      }
      case "DELETE_TODO": {
        this.deleteTodo(action.id);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}

const todoStore = new TodoStore;
dispatcher.register(todoStore.handleActions.bind(todoStore));
window.dispatcher = dispatcher
export default todoStore;
```

My TodoActions.js

```
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";

export function createTodo(text) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "CREATE_TODO",
    text,
  });
}

export function deleteTodo(id) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "DELETE_TODO",
    id,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `createTodo` as a method of the `TodoStore` class, so that will work when accessed via `this`, but you haven't defined a `deleteTodo` method as a member of the `TodoStore` class, so the `deleteTodo` method is not going to be accessible by calling `this` which refers to an instance of the `TodoStore` class.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. I saw that I forgot to declare a delete method `deleteTodo` in `TodoStore.js`. Could it be because of that?

Comment: Exactly, those methods don't exist on the class, they are stand-alone functions inside in the "TodoActions" module, and therefore don't need the `this` keyword to access them so long as you've imported them from the module

Comment: Yeah, but I do have a `createTodo` method within the same class(`TodoStore`) that I am using to create a method, so I am using a method within the same class and I am not importing them from `TodoActions.js`

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that ... Just to clear up confusion, I would not name your action creator functions the exact same as your class methods that handle the actions, the matching names threw me for a minute

Comment: I'll make sure I change the names